# How do I click a button that has no ID using (Apify's) Puppeteer?

Tags: button, puppeteer, clickable, apify

I am using [Apify's puppeteer](https://www.apify.com/docs/actor) to login to [this website](https://www.sunpass.com/vector/account/home/accountLogin.do). I did research similar questions but to no avail.

I am having trouble finding the clickable id/element for the main Login button seen on the [linked login page](https://www.sunpass.com/vector/account/home/accountLogin.do). Currently, my code reads like this:

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
const input = await Apify.getValue('INPUT');

const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.sunpass.com/vector/account/home/accountLogin.do');

// Login
await page.type('#tt_username1', input.username);
await page.type('#tt_loginPassword1', input.password);
await page.waitFor(2000);
await page.click('#entryform input');
await page.waitForNavigation();

// Get cookies
const cookies = await page.cookies();

// Use cookies in other tab or browser
const page2 = await browser.newPage();
await page2.setCookie(...cookies);
await page2.goto('https://www.sunpass.com/vector/account/transactions/webtransactionSearch.do'); // Opens page as logged user

await browser.close();

console.log('Done.');
```

With the id `entryform` I receive the following error: `Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement`

With the id `loginP` I receive the following error: `No node found for selector`

I used XPath to locate these, it offered no other ids of use. Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to find a clickable element for this login button, or any other method.

Answer (score 5):

You have to try another selector.
I tried `button[name="btnLogin"]` and it worked.

tested code:

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const input = await Apify.getValue('INPUT');

    const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.sunpass.com/vector/account/home/accountLogin.do');

    // Login
    await page.type('#tt_username1', input.username);
    await page.type('#tt_loginPassword1', input.password);
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.click('button[name="btnLogin"]');
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    // Get cookies
    const cookies = await page.cookies();

    // Use cookies in other tab or browser
    const page2 = await browser.newPage();
    await page2.setCookie(...cookies);
    await page2.goto('https://www.sunpass.com/vector/account/transactions/webtransactionSearch.do'); // Opens page as logged user

    await browser.close();

    console.log('Done.');
});
```

Comment: I have tested the above code in an Actor but the Task output shows: "`TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded.`" I tried all three of the non-beta Base Images. I don't know whether it is the first page or second page causing that... Of course, I don't have an account at the source site; I have an INPUT like this in both the Task and the Actor (because I don't know which is right)... `{
  "username": "foo",
  "password": "bar"
}`

Comment: They have to change the CSS selector for the submit button. You have to find right selector on the page.

Answer (score 0):

During my test of the login form on a desktop the "LOGIN" button could be found with this selector:

```
button[name=btnLogin].btn-large
```