# How to click button with no Selector, Class, or Name

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've been using Puppeteer for about a week now but I can't for the life of me figure out how to click on this button:

```html
<input type="button" value="Dismiss this error">
```

It has a dynamic selector that changes every time the page is opened so I can't use waitForSelector, I also tried using some code from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904802/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-website-using-puppeteer-without-any-class-id-as/52906547) Post but I'm new to JS so I didn't really know how to adapt it for my purposes, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi not sure, maybe search for input of type button `await page.click('input[type="button"]');` or `input[value='"Dismiss this error"']` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165242/how-do-i-click-a-button-that-has-no-id-using-apifys-puppeteer

Comment: Don't you mean `input[value='Dismiss this error']`?  Why is the value triple-quoted?

Comment: doesn't seem like that's working

Comment: it returns  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No node found for selector: input[value='Dismiss this error']